# Программная клавиатура

Tags: android

Как можно управлять программной клавиатурой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html). Пример использования: [Как показать клавиатуру для EditText?](http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/inputmethodmanager/show-softkeyboard-for-edittext)